# Regex for TLD field in url

Tags: php, regex, url

I am trying to allow links based on it's top level domain. For example, only .edu domains.

This is a PHP application and I currently use `.*\.edu`.

This works fine for most parts, however this also allows other links such as `www.facebook.com/example.edu`

How can I filter url's using regex, only if .edu is part of domain and not as a substring.

Comment: Is http:// and https:// optional at the beginning of the domain name? What about ftp:// or other protocols?

Comment: `preg_match('~://[^/]*\.edu(?![^/])~', $url)`

Comment: @Mathias-S Yes. They are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

Here is the regex

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.edu?(\/.*)?$
```